# Itext LargeElement and splitRows option

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, pdfptable

I'm trying to create a pdf containing a big table with itext v5.5.3.

I need :

- memory management
- repeating headers (1 row)
- disabling rows split

With the code below, everything works fine :

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    //table.setSplitRows(false);
    //table.setComplete(false);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {table.addCell("Header " + i);}     

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        table.addCell("Test " + i);
        //if (i%5 == 0) {document.add(table);}
     }

    //table.setComplete(true);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
```

If I add memory management (adding table to document every 5 cells), I'm losing first header :

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    //table.setSplitRows(false);
    table.setComplete(false);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {table.addCell("Header " + i);}     

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        table.addCell("Test " + i);
        if (i%5 == 0) {document.add(table);}
    }

    table.setComplete(true);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
```

If i add memory management + setSplitRows(false), I lose all headers and some lines :

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    table.setSplitRows(false);
    table.setComplete(false);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {table.addCell("Header " + i);}     

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        table.addCell("Test " + i);
        if (i%5 == 0) {document.add(table);}
    }

    table.setComplete(true);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
```

I've done some tests and with itext version 2.1.7.js2, all three test cases are working correctly.

So, bug or not bug ? What can I do to make this working ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a regression, so I've added a fix for this issue to the iText library. (Revision 6630).

It will be included in the 5.5.4 release, which is due in two-three weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem does not present itself if you replace

```
if (i % 5 == 0) {
    document.add(table);
}
```

by

```
int x = 5; // or any other value higher than your PdfPTable number of columns
if (i % 10 == x) {
    document.add(table);
}
```

The apparent reason for this problem is that iText doesn't want to include a table with only a header and one partial row. This is currently a workaround, but we're looking to find the core issue and to fix it.

Comment: Workaround works, but I will accept the official fix response. Thanks